# How can I theme a file link in a specific file field?

Tags: theming, hooks, 10

I have a file field (*pdf_via_email*). I need to do some heavy theming to the link of this field, so I would like to know how I can create a custom file link template specific to this field.

I tried the following preprocess hook with a custom template (*field--field-pdf-via-email.html.twig*), but Drupal is not picking up the suggested template. (*global* is the theme machine name.)

```php
function global_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  // Check if this is a file link associated with the 'pdf_via_email' field.
  if ($variables['file']->hasField('pdf_via_email')) {
    // Add a custom template suggestion for this field.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'file_link__pdf_via_email';
  }
}
```

I am stuck here, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.